# Call project() in subdirectories

Tags: cmake, build-system

Is it legal to call the project CMake function in a subdirectory when it was called in the root CMakeLists.txt? I intend to use this because it sets PROJECT_VERSION which I cann access in my configure files.

Comment: It is actually good practice to call `project()` in your subfolders, see https://www.slideshare.net/DanielPfeifer1/cmake-48475415 for more info (slide 24).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely legal. Each sub-directory can be a project(). It is generally recommended, at least for every independent "component" of the total project.